# Re-ordering Columns in a CSV file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a CSV file without headers that want reordered based on a config file .
[image: Input CSV on the left ;example config file on the right]

I'm using this code to do it

```
Dim csvFile As String = "C:\Text.csv"
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile)

Dim outFile As String = "C:\Text2.csv"
Dim data As String()

Dim format As String = "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}"

Using fs As New StreamWriter(outFile, False)
    For Each s As String In lines

        data = s.Split(","c)

        fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format,
                                   data(0),
                                   data(1),
                                   data(2),
                                   data(3),
                                   data(4),
                                   data(5)
                                 )
                    )
    Next
End Using
```

However since i wanted it to be dynamic , I wrote a function which reads the Config file and generates output for the format string.

the code looks like

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Filepath)
           Dim outFile As String = "C:\Out.csv"
            Dim data As String()

            Dim format As String = CReadConfig.ReadConfigsource(ConfigFilepath)

            Dim str As String


            Using fs As New StreamWriter(outFile, False)

                For Each s As String In lines

                    data = s.Split(","c)
                    ' specifiy the columns to write in
                    ' the order desired

                    Form1.TextBox1.Text = CReadConfig.ReadConfigtarget(ConfigFilepath)

                    str = CReadConfig.ReadConfigtarget(ConfigFilepath)


                    fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format, CReadConfig.ReadConfigtarget(ConfigFilepath)))
```

the output of the functions are as follows

> CReadConfig.ReadConfigsource(ConfigFilepath) = {0},{1},{2},{3}
>   CReadConfig.ReadConfigtarget(ConfigFilepath)  =
>   data(3),data(2),data(1),data(0)

However i am getting an error
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

When  i replace `CReadConfig.ReadConfigtarget(ConfigFilepath)` function with its output

> data(3),data(2),data(1),data(0)

the code works, however when replaced with a function that gives the same output,i get the error mentioned above.

Can someone please tell how to go about this.or is there a simpler way to achieve the reordering.

uploaded 
Data : http://www.filedropper.com/data_14
config file:

```
Source,Target
1,2
2,3
3,1
4,4
5,6
6,5
```

Comment: You can read the values in `List(Of List(Of String))` Each element in the outer list contains a row (list of fields). That way you can order them as you want. After that write these lists to file

Comment: You cannot abstract the data references to a string `data(3),data(2),data(1),data(0)` that part does not need to be in the config file.   the `data()` args to WriteLine would stay in the same order always - just change the "map" used for the `format` argument.  You still havent shown the actual data in the config file which would help us get a complete picture.  If we had that, we could help with the code to convert it to the `format` string required.

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks for responding,The picture attached shows the config file. it is a CSV file with two columns the first one is the initial position of the column and the second one is the new position of the column.

Comment: A picture is not the same as the actual data.  It may represent the concept very well, but it is not the actual data.  I cant give you a way to read/parse/store the config data into a working format string without seeing the actual data.  No one can, and that is the thing you seem stuck on at the moment.

Comment: @Plutonix thank you for being patient, I have uploaded the data

Comment: Ok, better!  See, I did not know the CFG was also a CSV.  Do you make these, do you control the format? A comment on another post you said the 'data' column count could change - does that mean different files?  How many?  Just a few or lots?  The mechanism I would use would be different for a many versus just a few.  Also, `PasteBin.com` tends to work better for that sort of thing - the CFG is small enough for the post.  One more thing: the data file has decimal values in it - are those ever in a euro type format (`12,34` vs `12.34`)>

Comment: @plutonix i will not have control over the number of columns in the input file. The config file is something the end user would edit to generate an output in an expected format

Comment: do they edit it *directly* like in notepad or is there an app interface?  I have a version to help with the format, but I am having to make many guesses